# Passing down props returning undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

**main component**

```jsx
const items = [{name: 'a'}, {name: 'b'}, {name: 'c'}]
render={() => (
    <LinksComponent
        items={items}
    />)}
```

**Links Component**

```jsx
const LinksComponent = ({ items }) => (
    <div>
        {items.map((item) => {
            return <div>{item.name}</div>
        })}
   </div>
)
```

I must be missing something really simple but I have my main component and this react-router renders my link component. it is all wired up correctly because when I had `hello world` rendering it showed. now I'm trying to pass items down can't seem to display them. it keeps saying it can't read map of undefined. any ideas?

Comment: LComponent and LinksComponent is not same

Comment: How are you exporting and respectively importing LinksComponent

Comment: @mehulmpt ah typo in my post. THIS IS NOT THE FIX. but thanks anyway

Comment: but it did fix it actually coz it helped me spot something else!

Comment: @TheWalrus what was the fix?

Comment: @abdul I passed the props down one level too few

Answer (score 0):

Okay I worked on it. I passed props down at max 2 level. And also added `Router` wrapping before `div`.

See the solution here - https://codesandbox.io/s/ly63qwjm49

Comment: this is react-router render, not react-dom render

Comment: @TheWalrus Yes I edited the answer, check out the link